# Showing Custom Taxonomy Post Counts in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created custom posts with custom taxonomy categories in wordpress. I have also created html link and i would like to show the custom post count related to the html  next to it.

I have defined the listing categories in my functions php as:

```
define( 'VA_LISTING_CATEGORY', 'listing_category' );
```

and have the listing category function as :

```
function the_listing_categories( $listing_id = 0 ) {

$listing_id = $listing_id ? $listing_id : get_the_ID();

$cats = get_the_listing_categories( $listing_id );
if ( !$cats ) return;

$_cats = array();

foreach($cats as $cat) {
    $_cats[] = html_link( get_term_link( $cat ), $cat->name );
}

$cats_list = implode( ', ', $_cats);

printf( __( 'Listed in %s', APP_TD ), $cats_list );

   }
```

Please help in regards to how I can show these?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share with us the code you are using, so we can properly suggest the correct way?

Comment: thanks have added my code